How to send POST call with payload in body from javascript to ASP.NET Web API with Windows auth enabled
I am creating an ASP.NET Web API using C# expecting a payload in the POST body. Windows auth is enabled on IIS.
public class GenericController : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/{version}/{user}/Generic/UpdateData")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage UpdateData([FromBody] GenericPayload parameter)
    {
    }
}

Every time I attempt to access it from React or JavaScript code, I encounter an access denied problem. I'm interested in finding out if it's even feasible to achieve success with this call using JavaScript.

ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core? Where does the JS code come from? Windows Authentication is performed between the browser and IIS, not the code. If the code comes from the same site, the browser authenticates to the server before retrieving the HTML and code. That's convenient but also a problem - any code running in other tabs gets authenticated as well. That's why MS warns against using Windows Auth with SPAs

You can try to use fetch.
fetch('http://localhost:4200/api/version/user/Generic/UpdateData', 
{
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Negotiate' },
     body: JSON.stringify({ //... your payload }),
     credentials: 'include' 
 })
   .then(response => response.json())
   .then(data => console.log(data))
   .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));

The credentials: include option is mandatory as it allows the browser to send the authenticated user's credentials with the request.
